# DatePickerDialog Header text margin issue Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am using DatePickerDialog in CustomDialogFragment. It works fine in all the devices, but getting issue in Moto G phone having OS 6.0.1 (Marshmallow). Displayng 2018 and Fri to the extreme left. But in other devices it works fine.

Here is my code snippet and screenshot attached:-

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    if(getArguments().getString("activity").equalsIgnoreCase("RegisterActivity")){
                        RegisterActivity.etExp.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    } else {
                        if (getArguments().getString("from", "").equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
                            SortRightFragment.tvStartDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                        }
                        if (getArguments().getString("from", "").equalsIgnoreCase("End")) {
                            SortRightFragment.tvEndDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                        }
                    }
                    datePickerDialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.text_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                    }
                }
            });


            datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.text_clear), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                        if(getArguments().getString("activity").equalsIgnoreCase("RegisterActivity")){
                            RegisterActivity.etExp.setText("");
                        } else {
                            if (getArguments().getString("from", "").equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
                                SortRightFragment.tvStartDate.setText("");
                            }
                            if (getArguments().getString("from", "").equalsIgnoreCase("End")) {
                                SortRightFragment.tvEndDate.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Both date and time picker have some known bugs, even in the latest versions.  I don't know the Moto G Android phone or Marshmallow, but if this is just a small percentage of your expected users, I would say just forget this and keep coding.  The dialog is still usable, readable, and this is not a blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DatePickerDialog` extends `AlertDialog` maybe this will work for you:  
First find the title TextView and then set its padding:

```
TextView tv = datePickerDialog.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"));
```

This would work too:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) datePickerDialog.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
```

Change the padding values to what you like:

```
tv.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);
```